# Adding FGallery to my app

Tags: ios, button, uibutton, back

Still new and learning so please please bear with me. I have two issues regarding this topic. A little background. I have developed a app that has 5 tab bar items. One tabBarItems' view (the home view) has 5 buttons. One of these buttons loads the RootViewController for the open source [FGallery Slideshow Project] (https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone) created by Grant Davis. I incorporated a good portion of the features into my app. Using a UIButton in HomeViewController I push to the RootViewController which is edited to suite my needs. I made some additions and omissions.

**ISSUE 1:** MOST IMPORTANT
 I have a problem with the app crashing on the Go Back Button (Home if your in the initial load of the RootViewController).After the RootViewController loads I can step through the gallery functions just fine. If I click back (to the previous view) it will crash on Going back to HomeViewController with the following error in the app delegate:

**"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=11, address=0x10)"**

it appears on this line of code:

```
#import "MyAppleAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MyAppleAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

ARC is omitted on the classes that make up the Gallery. The rest of the app uses ARC.

Target build is 7.1. Everything works fine if loaded using 6.1 by programmatically targeting Legacy UI but only in the simulator. I have not had a chance to test it on a device running iOS 6.1 only 7.1. Of course with all of apples recent changes It is best to just build for 7.1. Sad thing is when I started this app 6.1 was the standard :(

**HomeViewController UIButton to gallery:**

```
-(IBAction)showGallery:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gallery"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

}
```

**ISSUE 2:** NOT AS IMPORTANT I AM SURE I CAN FIGURE THIS ONE OUT BUT..

In the view that shows the toolbar which controls which image is showing. The tool bar is hidden under the TabBar along with half of the caption container. In iOS 6; No problem, they stack on top of each other the way they are so-pose to.

Thanks in advance for any help I realize this question might be a bit much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my current main issue by converting the FGallery to use ARC.